# Pebble crashes on `realloc`, but only in a certain function

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc, pebble-sdk

I'm using a custom vector in a Pebble app.
Pebble is crashing on the call to `realloc`.

**main.c**

```
#include <pebble.h>
#include "movement.h"

static PointArray point_array;

int main(void) {;
    point_array_create(&point_array, 1);
    GPoint point1 = (GPoint){.x = 1, .y = 1};
    GPoint point2 = (GPoint){.x = 2, .y = 2};
    GPoint point3 = (GPoint){.x = 3, .y = 3};

    point_array_push(&point_array, point1);
    point_array_push(&point_array, point2);
    point_array_push(&point_array, point3);
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "Done\n");
}
```

**movement.c**

```
#include "movement.h"
#include "pebble.h"


static void point_array_resize(PointArray *point_array){
  point_array->capacity *= 2;
  size_t new_size = point_array->capacity * sizeof(GPoint) + sizeof(GPoint);
  point_array->points = (GPoint*)realloc(point_array->points, new_size);
}


void point_array_create(PointArray *arr, int capacity) {
    arr->points = (GPoint*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(GPoint));
    arr->length = 0;
    arr->capacity = capacity;
}

void point_array_push(PointArray *point_array, GPoint point) {

  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "pushing");

  if (point_array->length > point_array->capacity) {
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "resizing");
    point_array_resize(point_array);
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "successful resize");
  }
  point_array->points[point_array->length] = point;
  point_array->length++;
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "+ length");
}
```

**movement.h**

```
#include <pebble.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
  GPoint *points;
  int length;
  int capacity;
} PointArray;

void point_array_create(PointArray *arr, int capacity);

void point_array_push(PointArray *point_array, GPoint point);

void point_array_destroy(PointArray *point_array, GPoint point);

GPoint move(GPoint point, float distance, float degrees);
```

The logs show that the app is crashing at the call to `realloc`:

```
[DEBUG] movement.c:20: pushing
[DEBUG] movement.c:29: + length
[DEBUG] movement.c:20: pushing
[DEBUG] movement.c:29: + length
[DEBUG] movement.c:20: pushing
[DEBUG] movement.c:23: resizing
```

Here's what I tried:

- The code runs fine on both GCC and Clang (!).
- I verified that `point_array` and `point_array->points` are not null and
- `new_size` is larger than the existing size of `point_array->points`.
- I looked at [this issue](https://forums.pebble.com/t/invalid-realloc-implementation/11892), which doesn't seem to apply.
- I tried calling `realloc` at the bottom of `point_array_create`, and it works fine. It just doesn't work in `point_array_resize`.

Comment: If the initial capacity is `0`, the resize code does not work.  You should make sure capacity is non zero when resizing.

Comment: @chqrlie good point - the capacity is non-zero and `point_array->points` has stuff in it. For example `point_array->points[0].x == 10`

Comment: There may be hidden memory violations in other parts of your program. If your program or part of your program works on x86 linux, try valgrind and make sure you don't see any errors related to your program.

Comment: Why do you reallocate an extra slot in `resize` and not in `create`

Comment: Why the different size formulas?   `capacity * sizeof(GPoint)` and `point_array->capacity * sizeof(GPoint) + sizeof(GPoint)`?

Comment: Minor: `point_array->capacity *= 2;` is not protected from overflow.  Type of field `capacity` not shown.

Comment: `foo = realloc(foo, some_size);` is always **wrong** (unless `foo` is guaranteed to be `NULL`, but then just write `NULL` and not `foo`) because it's a possible memory leak. `realloc` doesn't `free` on failure.

Comment: "The code runs fine on both GCC and Clang (!)." - really? did valgrind tell you that for confirmation? This seriously needs a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for without it, it is destined for closure.

Comment: @jxh sure, I can post an example. I just need to chop my code down to the smallest unit that still has the problem. Please don't close.

Comment: @WhozCraig working on a reproducible sample, will have by 10 EST

Comment: @chqrlie, that's a good question. I guess I don't need to allocate an extra slot.

Comment: @jxh, I updated the question to provide a complete program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `point_array_push`, you test if you need to resize your points at the top, but the test is wrong. You only resize if the length has exceeded capacity, which means you have already overrun your array.

Instead, check to see if the length has reached capacity.

```
  if (point_array->length == point_array->capacity) {
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "resizing");
    point_array_resize(point_array);
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "successful resize");
  }
```